# Unable to establish a neo4j - bolt driver connection in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, neo4j, neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver

I am trying to create a connection between my html embedded javascript and my neo4j database by running the index.html in Chrome. I have reduced the source of the problem to 'neo4j' not being recognised. So the error thrown will be of the type:

Cannot read property ['driver'/'basic'/etc...] of undefined.

In this case I have assumed that 'undefined' is referring to 'neo4j', which would mean that I am not implementing 'neo4j-web.min.js' correctly.

The below block of code is extracted from my index.html and has been taken from:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver

```
<script src="node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/browser/neo4j-web.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost:7474", neo4j.auth.basic(neo4j, 
  neo4j));
</script>
```

Given that the issue seems very localised to this code, I spared everyone the rest of the document. If further context is missing, I'd be happy to provide it.

Comment: Have you installed the `neo4j-driver` module using npm?

Comment: Yes. Just double checked anyway. Version 3.10.10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The neo4j-driver module uses an odd system whereby you have to specify which version of the API you want to use.

```
<script src="node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/browser/neo4j-web.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  neo4j = neo4j.v1
  var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost:7474", neo4j.auth.basic(neo4j, 
  neo4j));
</script>
```

Comment: Now this makes sense (from neo4j docs):

<script src="lib/browser/neo4j-web.min.js"></script>
This will make a global neo4j object available, where you can access the v1 API at neo4j.v1:

Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @varbrad 
My 2cts: check the servername
You are using the alias localhost