# Visualize neo4j data on HTML page using Neo4j Javascript Driver (node.js) and D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, d3.js, neo4j

I want to dynamically visualize neo4j data (in tabular form) on a HTML page using neo4j javascript driver. The visualization is done using D3.js. 
So far I can establish the connection between neo4j and javascript (node.js) using driver:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver

and can read the neo4j data in console (Windows). Now further I want to 
visualize the same table on a HTML page using D3.js.

Considering the following question:

[Unable to establish a neo4j - bolt driver connection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205354/unable-to-establish-a-neo4j-bolt-driver-connection-in-javascript) ,

how can I create a connection between html embedded javascript and neo4j? Is it possible without creating node.js server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the "Session API:" part of the page you linked.
Use the onnext callback to transfer the data of each returned record into some structure you will use with d3.js

Comment: I tried to bind using session API, but I am not getting complete list on the HTTP page. I get only first element from the list in neo4j. I created server and defined driver in the same .js file. Can I write d3.js code and server code in same file? Relevant Code: 
'code' MATCH (u) Return u.name; 
var resn = record.get('name'); 
var http = require('http'); http.createServer(function (req, res) { res.write(resn); 
 res.end();}).listen(8080); 'code' 
thanks in advance. @Jerome B